# how to use count with a regex

Tags: python, regex, split, count

Suppose I have this string

```
text = "microsoft,javascript java microsoft office"
```

If I want to count how many times microsoft office exists

```
print(text.count("microsoft office")) # returns 1
```

But if I want to count how many times java exists, without considering javascript

```
print(text.count("java")) # returns 2 but it should return 1
```

I taught of using split from re :

```
import re 
count = 0
text = "microsoft,javascript java microsoft office"
words = re.split("[ ,]", text)
for word in words:
    if word == "java":
        count += 1

print(count) # returns 1
```

It will work for java but not for microsoft office as it will split by space and the if condition will not be satisfied  `if word == "microsoft"` `if word == "office"`

What I want is a way to mix count and split in such a way that can work for the two examples

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using findall operation in regex , try this code

```
import re
text = "microsoft,javascript java microsoft office"
word = input("enter a word to check its occurence ")
check = re.findall(word,text)
print(word +" occured "+str(len(check))+ " times")
```

Comment: it returns 2 for java because there's javascript

Comment: I understand  in this case, you just need to add "java"  followed by space